# Value ranges for iOS Core Image Filters Exposure, Hue, Sepia, Temparature, Tint, Vignette

Tags: ios, core-image, imagefilter

I would like to know value ranges for following CIFilters in iOS. From different places I've found following values. Are they correct? and any reference is greatly appreciate to find them all at one place?

```
CIExposureAdjust - inputEV (-10.0f - 10.0f)
CIHueAdjust - inputAngle (-180.0f - 180.0f converted to Radians)
CISepiaTone - inputIntensity (0.0f - 1.0f)
CITemperatureAndTint - inputNeutral
CITemperatureAndTint - inputTargetNeutral
CIVignette - inputRadius
CIVignette - inputIntensity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query the inputs to get their ranges. Some are infinite, some have minimums and maximums. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_concepts/ci_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH2-TPXREF101) describes how to do so:

> Filter names and attributes provide all the information you need to build a user interface that allows users to choose a filter and control its input parameters. The attributes for a filter tell you how many input parameters the filter has, the parameter names, the data type, and the minimum, maximum, and default values.